# How to add a cell to a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to be able to add 1 cell to the top of a UITableView after the user clicks on a button. How can I achieve this?

Update:
I also want to hide the cell if the user clicks another button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either call `UITableView`'s [`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW38) to animate the insertion. Otherwise, you can just update your datasource without calling this method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you have to use the Navigation Controller, this is because once the user clicks the button your are suppose to send the user to a new view that edits and adds the new cell to the UITableView.